# Don't have write permission in partition

Tags: linux, permissions, partition, windows

In my PC I have installs Windows7 and then Ubuntu as OSes.
When I try to access other partitions ( E: and F: which I'm using from Winsows7 OS) it get mount without any issue and can read and modify the files. Only thing I can't do is create or rename file on that partitions.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default in-kernel NTFS driver only has limited write support; you need to use an NTFS driver that supports those operations. Take a look at [`ntfs-3g`](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/).

Comment: Awesome!!!
Thank you Chris. After installing ntfs-3g and remount the partition, it worked :)